# Git branch master contents visible to non git users

Tags: git

in my workgroup we are four developers and we usually commit our work on our git repos on our PCs and time by time we push our mods to a bare git repository stored in a RAID server.

Now, we have a problem because we have several colleagues who need to view files (just a read access) stored on the server repository, but they don't even know what does git means and they simply want to use a samba connection to the server to access the data.

Unfortunately a bare repository viewed in a folder view contains just the .git folder and it is useless for them. So we tried to transform the repository in non-bare, but in this way we have problems in pushing our mods to the server repository, because the master must be checked out to be viewed, and if checked out it is locked for push..

Do you have any hints for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's pretty simple solution: make a non-bare reflection repository which is automatically updated each time the main bare repo receives changes in a selected branch (I suppose, `master`).

The reflection repository should reside in the same workstation as the main one and it'd be nice if it would reside on the same filesystem to preserve space and speedup operations.

You need to use [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) particularly the `post-receive` hook in your main (bare repo). Make the hook to fetch newer changes from the main repo to the reflection, then update the worktree to the selected branch, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

cd /path/to/reflection/repo
unset GIT_DIR
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Beware of `$GIT_DIR`, which in a post-receive hook is set to `.`, which breaks the remaining git commands unless you unset (or alter) it.